# Export Open Office doc to CHM

Tags: pdf, openoffice, chm

I am creating help for my program in Open Office Writer. Help has link, image, text. How can I export OOWriter file to chm? I tied to use standart export, but I had bad result. I need export with support:
1. Link.
2. H1, H2, H3.
3. Image.

I can convert OOwriter file to pdf and export pdf to chm.

Do you know program for export to chm?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the [HTML Help Workshop](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=00535334-c8a6-452f-9aa0-d597d16580cc)? Save it to HTML and pass it through the HTML Help Workshop to generate a CHM.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.